# How can i set up a database package deployment on subdomains with nginx

Tags: nginx, joomla, subdomain

i finding it quite difficult to understand how to begin setting up a a "quick launch" website system where someone would enter a subdomain entry and it would launch an instance of joomla or wordpress in that subdomain. There is an example on https://www.joomla.com/ where it just takes a subdomain, email and password. Sorry if this is a complicated question. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update nginx, you'd want your webapp to write a configuration file to /etc/nginx/conf.d (assuming a standard linux install) and then execute a "sudo service nginx reload" to reload the configuration and update the running webserver gracefully.

The database for each user would be a set of SQL statements to create their individual databases (by username) on your single database server, or any set of them scaled linearly (for instance, if you have 5 db servers, users could be partitioned evenly across them by userId % 5.

Comment: Thank you! That sounds alot better then i thought, would you be interested in being hired on upwork.com for this service?